# Drawing bitmap to screen Gloss Haskell

Tags: forms, haskell, bitmap, drawing, gloss

For uni I have this assignment where I need to code a simple game, im now having issues with drawing the player object to the screen. I have the following functions:

```
data Player = MkPlayer {
                playerpos :: Point,
                playerradius :: Int,
                playerbullets :: [Bullet]
              }

instance Renderable Player where
  render (MkPlayer pos rad _ ) = do picture <- loadBMP "./images/player.bmp"
                                    return picture
.
.
.

view :: GameState -> IO Picture
view (MkGameState False (MkBoard player _) _) = render player
```

this displays the image to the center of the screen. But of course, I want to draw the image at the players position with the right size. How do i implement this? Any help at alll is aprreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

before return use [translate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.13.2.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Picture.html#v:translate) function

```hs
instance Renderable Player where
  render (MkPlayer (x,y) rad _ ) = do picture <- loadBMP "./images/player.bmp"
                                    return $ translate x y picture
```